# Multiple user's data updated from single form

Tags: php

Building an availability tracker for work.  I'm a little stuck with an admin part of the page.  I have it working for a single user to update or insert his availability (i.e. single form of drop-down boxes).  However, for the supervisor page, I can output everyone's availability using a while loop.  However, I'm not sure how to know which drop-down box is associated with a specific user/id.

```
        <?php
            if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
            {
                if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                {
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM availability WHERE week_start_date ='" 
                        . $_SESSION['display_date'] . "';";
                    mysqli_query($db, $query) or die ('Error querying database');

                    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

                // HERE IS WHERE I'M NOT SURE HOW TO UPDATE DATABASE
                }
            }

            $query = "SELECT * FROM availability WHERE week_start_date ='" 
                    . $_SESSION['display_date'] . "';";

            mysqli_query($db, $query) or die ('Error querying database');

            $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

            $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo "<label>" . $row['pilot_id'] . "</label>";
                echo "<br/>";
                echo "<label>Monday:</label><br/>";
                display_day("monday", $db);
                echo "<br/>";
                echo "<label>Tuesday:</label><br/>";
                display_day("tuesday", $db);
                echo "<br/>";
            }
        ?>
```

display_data is just a function that outputs the drop-down boxes.

```
function display_day($day, $db)
{
    echo "<select name=" . $day ."> "
        . "<option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>";

        $query = "SELECT * FROM availability_status";
        mysqli_query($db, $query) or die ('Error querying database');

        $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['status'] . "'>" . $row['status'] 
                . "</option>";
        }

    echo "</select>";
}
```

Do I need to somehow attach the primary key from the table of users to each drop-down box to know how to update the table?

Disclaimer:  I understand this is sloppy code and not production-worthy; I just need to get a prototype running.

Comment: You basically answered your own question. You have to set the users id in the value part of the select

Comment: @SuperDJ, I think I can use input arrays, no? "name = monday[]"

Comment: For file input it's possible yes for a normal text input I don't but give it a try

Comment: Of course. It's done by $_POST['monday']['index']